# Data not writing correctly to JSON file

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to write data to JSON file, but it is not writing it correctly and I can't find out why

```
import json

person = {
    "Name": "William", 
    "Age": 30,
    "full-time": True
}

personJSON = json.dumps(person, indent=4, sort_keys=True)

with open('person.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(personJSON, file)
```

This is what it writes to the file `"{\n    \"Age\": 30,\n    \"Name\": \"William\",\n    \"full-time\": true\n}"`

I've been looking online and the code seems fine to me

Comment: seems fine to me. What's wrong with it?

Comment: you have made `personJSON` as a string, then you are dumping the string as json to the file... dumping a string as JSON will escape the existing quotes and wrap the whole thing in double-quotes

Comment: json.dump takes dictionary as a first argument. However, you can still provide keyword argument `indent=4` in `json.dump` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `.dumps` and `.dump` subsequently, just use latter i.e. do

```
import json

person = {
    "Name": "William", 
    "Age": 30,
    "full-time": True
}

with open('person.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(person, file, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

Comment: but presumably they still want the `indent=4, sort_keys=True` part